# Insert into one table if no record exists in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I club this  two queries into one? Insert a record if a record does not exist in another table. I tried googling but I have only found solutions using joins, not in but here I guess there is no relation between this two tables. can I still insert into it with a single query

```
$res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 1 FROM bicds WHERE (bid = $pid] AND uid = $eid)
       OR (bid = $eid AND uid = $pid) LIMIT 1");

if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 0){
    mysqli_query($con,"Insert into t1 (pid,ust) values ($pid,$ust)");
 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You could write a stored procedure to do it but I'm curious about the reason.

Comment: @cjungel I googled on stored procedures , people say stored procedure should be avoided because they are fixed to database, no portability and when you change your database from mysql to some other oracle you have to recode everything also PHP provides mysqli_multi_query, I tried to think on how to return a value from mysqli_multi_query but unable to figure it out. I guess there must be some way to do this.

Comment: True, but using the LIMIT clause also means you're not being portable. It really depends on your requirements. How likely is your use case to require migration to a different database engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `insert . . . select`:

```
Insert into t1(pid, ust) 
    select $pid, $ust
    from dual
    where not exists (select 1 from bicds where bid = $pid AND uid = $eid);
```

This allows you to include a `where` clause in the `insert`.

Comment: It throws me error I think select clause should have table name after select $pid, $ust ?

Comment: @user3205479 . . . This is when you need `from dual` (although there are other solutions).

Comment: worked like a charm but out of curiosity I wanna know what does dual mean here? and I just read not exists is quite slow. you can achieve it using left join? is that possible to do with left joins? Your help is greatly appriecated if you can explain me with a join query

Comment: @user3205479 . . . `dual` is a table that has one row and one column.  It is used when you just have to have a table in the `from` clause (MySQL doesn't support a `where` without a `from` for instance).  The logic and usage of it come from Oracle.

Comment: +1 but it's worth mentioning that `dual` is not a real table, it's a special table name but it's not actually stored anywhere. It has one row, but I don't think it has any columns. It's like C. J. Date's 0-tuple `TABLE_DEE`.

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . Amusing.  `dual` appears to be a reserved word in MySQL, hence "built-in" to the language.  It isn't a reserved word in Oracle, because it really is a dummy table.  And, it has its own Wikipedia entry (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table).  How many database tables can say that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CASE condition in query along with a check on number of rows as the condition.

```
   select (count *) from FROM bicds WHERE (bid = $pid] AND uid = $eid)
   OR (bid = $eid AND uid = $pid) LIMIT 1")
```

This will be 0 or NULL if table doesn't exist.